# Каким образом генерируется type (способ, которым определено местоположение) в ответе от Яндекс.Локатора?

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Насколько я понял из статьи [на хабре](https://habr.com/company/yandex/blog/162955/), при обращении к API Яндекс.Локатора с запросом, который содержит одновременно информацию о GSM-сетях и о Wi-Fi-сетях, сервис будет определять координаты одновременно и по GSM-сетям, и по Wi-Fi-сетям.

Какой способ, которым определено местоположение, в таком случае будет содержаться в ответе от сервиса?

В [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/locator/doc/dg/concepts/geolocation-docpage/) указано три способа:

- gsm — по сотам мобильных сетей.
- wifi — по точкам доступа Wi-Fi.
- ip — по IP-адресу.

Верно ли, что при наличии информации о Wi-Fi в запросе, в ответе всегда будет указан type "wifi"?

Или возможны ситуации, когда при наличии маленького количества информации о Wi-Fi-сетях и большого количества информации о GSM-сетях, сервис решит, что при помощи GSM-сетей координаты определяются с меньшей погрешностью, и ответ сервиса будет содержать type "gsm", несмотря на наличие информации о Wi-Fi-сетях?

**Upd.** Экспериментальным путём выяснил, что даже при наличии информации о Wi-Fi-сетях в ответе может вернуться type "ip" или "gsm".

Выбрал 1000 точек, для которых известна информация о GSM-сетях и о Wi-Fi-сетях, для каждой послал три запроса в Яндекс.Локатор:

1. По GSM-сетям
2. По Wi-Fi-сетям
3. И по GSM-сетям, и по Wi-Fi-сетям

~200 точек при наличии информации о Wi-Fi-сетях присылают type != "wifi". Координаты, которые получены только по Wi-Fi отличаются от комбинированных данных (GSM + Wi-Fi) в среднем на ~ 100000 метров. При этом для этих ~200 точек координаты, которые получены по GSM + Wi-Fi, почти всегда совпадают с координатами, полученными по GSM-сетям. Ответ на запрос GSM + Wi-Fi содержит type "gsm". Ответ на запрос Wi-Fi содержит type "ip", координаты соответствуют Красной площади в Москве, погрешность равна 100000.

Думаю, это связано с тем, что БД Яндекса не может содержать информацию по всем Wi-Fi точкам, поэтому когда в запросе имеется информация о неизвестных Wi-Fi точках, координаты не могут быть получены.

Исключение составляют 5 точек, они имеют координаты, у которых GSM + Wi-Fi отличаются и от GSM (в среднем на ~3000 метров) и от Wi-Fi (в среднем на ~100000 метров). Ответ на запрос GSM + Wi-Fi содержит type "wifi"

Answer (score 0):

> Верно ли, что при наличии информации о Wi-Fi в запросе, в ответе всегда будет указан type "wifi"?

Верно. Если в запросе есть полная информация - будет ставиться *type* **wifi**.
Даже в случае разрешения неоднозначности (например, wifi "засветился" в двух местах), сравнивая с gsm-данными, будет ставиться *type* **wifi**.

Соответственно, тип **gsm** будет стоять, если нет актуальных данных о wifi. И **ip** будет в случае отсутствия данных по wifi и gsm.

Физический смысл — наиболее точный источник данных, повлиявший на ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я обновил вопрос, и мои экспериментальные результаты почему-то расходятся с Вашим ответом :(
Можете прокомментировать мои результаты, пожалуйста?

Comment: Ваши экспериментальные данные никак не противоречат моему ответу. Внимательно читайте: "gsm будет стоять, если нет актуальных данных о wifi". Если актуальных данных о сети wifi нет, то все так как вы и догадались выше.